# How to reverse .astype(str) in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I had to remove duplicate rows in my dataframe which had list values in it.

So I used

```
pd_data['douban_info_string'] = pd_data['douban_info'].astype(str)
```

Where 'douban_info_string' had list values.

But now I need this list to compare with list of another data frame. But the list is changed into string now and I get this error

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: you can turn it back to list using `import ast` `pd_data['douban_info'].apply(ast.literal_eval)` ??

Comment: @anky_91 didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Use `pandas.eval`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'info':[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]})

df['info_str']=df['info'].astype(str)
df['info_str'][0]
# '[1, 2, 3]'

df['info_str'].apply(pd.eval)[0]
# [1,2,3]
```

Comment: Im getting this error ValueError: unknown type str224

Comment: @Miffy I believe your column contains non-list-like strs such as 'str224'.

Comment: My column had nested lists and after conversion its strings of lists

Comment: @Miffy And what is the elements of the nested list? do they only contain `int`s?

Comment: No they contain strings

Comment: each element of the columns is of this form "['t', 'e']". How do I convert this to ['t','e']

Comment: Can you post the entire message with the error `ValueError: unknown type str224 `?

Comment: ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numexpr/necompiler.py in getType(a)
    701     if kind == 'S':
    702         return bytes
--> 703     raise ValueError("unknown type %s" % a.dtype.name)
    704 
    705 

ValueError: unknown type str224

Answer (score 0):

Use `apply` with an if statement:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'info':[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], 'str224']})
df['info_str'] = df['info'].astype(str)
print(df['info_str'][0])
print(type(df['info_str'][0]))
print(df['info_str'].apply(lambda x: x if x in df['info'].tolist() else pd.eval(x))[0])
print(type(df['info_str'].apply(lambda x: x if x in df['info'].tolist() else pd.eval(x))[0]))
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
<class 'str'>
[1 2 3]
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
pd_data['douban_info_string_list'] = pd_data['douban_info_string'].map(lambda x: x.replace('[', '').replace(']', '').split(','))
```

Hope it helps.